# Why prettier put a comma ',' at the last element of the object

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, chart.js, prettier

In Visual studio code, When I am using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) in my app, prettier always put a comma at the end of the last data of the object 'label'. I think, it's create a bug which unable to show my chart on my browser. it show blank. Code is given bellow.

```html
let massPopChart2 = new Chart(myChart2, {
  type: "bar", // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
  data: {
    labels: [
      "1st Day",
      "2nd Day",
      "3rd Day",
      "4th Day",
      "5th Day",
      "6th Day",
      "7th Day",
    ],
  },
});
```

can anyone help me figure out why this happening?

Comment: You can change it by setting `'trailingComma': 'none'` in your prettier config.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> JavaScript has allowed trailing commas in array literals since the
> beginning, and later added them to object literals (ECMAScript 5) and
> most recently (ECMAScript 2017) to function parameters.

This is a relatively new change in syntax, but the basic idea is that by putting a comma on each line allows for:

1. Easier to add an item or re-order items. Before you always had to check the trailing comma and make sure it was present or removed depending on location.
2. Removes the need to have one line item be special because it lacks the `,`.
3. Allows for cleaner Git diffs.

You can read up on the full documentation if you like - it goes into further detail:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas

---

As far as the issue with your chart not displaying, unless you are using a very old browser, a trailing comma should not cause an error/information to not display.

Comment: i used latest fire fox and chrome browser

Comment: In the benefits, I would add that it makes cleaner diffs if you use git or another versioning system because without the last comma, you always change the previous line when you add an item at the end. As far as I know the JSON spec does not allow a comma at the end of the last element and it's a shame.

Comment: @Mig You are very right, the JSON spec will not let you have a trailing comma. I would suspect this would eventually change considering JSON is slightly related to javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the configuration of `prettier` extension.

There are two ways. Below one is mostly used.

1. Create a `.prettierrc` file at the root of your project and
   specifying the below configuration.

   {  "trailingComma": "es5" }
2. In order to honor the configuration make sure to enable the below
   setting in vs code configuration.

   "prettier.requireConfig": true

Comment: For additional context, including a list of the valid prettier `trailingComma` options, see [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#trailing-commas).

Answer (score 0):

Prettier adds those commas at the end just because if you wanna add another data after that you don't need to type a comma. it does the same for semicolons(;).

you got the error because you haven't provided datasets.

data takes an object which contains labels & datasets values.

```
{/* <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas> */}

// var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['1','2'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: '1st',
        data: '120',
        borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.red,
        backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(Utils.CHART_COLORS.red, 0.5),
      },
      {
        label: '2',
        data: '240',
        borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.red,
        backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue, 0.5),
      }
    ]
  },
//   options: {
//     indexAxis: 'y',
//     elements: {
//       bar: {
//         borderWidth: 2,
//       }
//     },
//     responsive: true,
//     plugins: {
//       legend: {
//         position: 'right',
//       },
//       title: {
//         display: true,
//         text: 'Chart.js Horizontal Bar Chart'
//       }
//     }
//   },
// };
```

you can know more about it on official docs  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html